# Exporting string with newline and tab symbols to LaTeX

Tags: output-formatting, latex, export

We have a string that has "tab" symbol between letters "B" and "C" and "newline" symbol between letters "C" and "D":

Input:

```
"A B\tC\nD"
```

Output:

[image]

The output is formatted accordingly to special symbols used.

But when I export the same string to LaTeX, the special symbols `\n` and `\t` are interpreted literally like so:

Input:

```
ExportString["A b\tc\nd", "TeXFragment"]
```

Output:

```
\[\text{A b$\backslash $tc$\backslash $newlined}\]
```

If you put this Latex code into some TeX file the document will display literally "A B\tC\nD" and without "tab" and "newline" symbols.

How to tell the Mathematica to export the special symbols into LaTeX accordingly?

Comment: Why don't you use `"Text"` as the format since you don't need any special TeX markup?

Comment: Because I want to save it into TeX file - that is why I exported it into `TeXFragment`.

Comment: Okay. What do you want the Mathematica output string result to be? Please include that information in your question.

Comment: Do you see the first output? That is what I want but not inside mathematica but inside TeX document. You can use instead `ExportString["A B\tC\nD", "TeX"]` then save the output string to file.tex then open that file and you will see that the output in the TeX file is without tab and newline.

Comment: A "TeX" or "LaTeX" file is just a file with text characters except there are conventions on how to interpret those text characters. Thus, in your case, what is the string of text characters that you want to be in the file? You need to specify that in your question. This seems to be a TeX question and not a Mathematica question.

Comment: How about `Export["str.tex", "A B\tC\nD", "Text"]`

Comment: @MelaGo: That does not work, you simply exported a text file not a TeX file, it does not matter that you you used ".tex" extensions.

Comment: @Somos: It is specified very well what characters I want in the TeX file. Can you read? Those characters are "A" followed by "SPACE" followed by "B" followed by "TAB" followed by "C" followed by "NEWLINE" followed by "D". It is a question on how Mathematica is exporting strings with special characters into TeX files. Mathematica is exporting special character "TAB" i.e. "\t" literally as "BACKSLASH" followed by "t" not as one symbol of "TAB". I think it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
txt =
 "\\begin{verbatim}
 A b\tc\nd
 \\end{verbatim}";
ExportString[txt, "Text"]
```

[image: result]

Comment: This seem to work. But it is just a manual workaround. Why it does not work with Mathematica's original functions that are built for exporting to TeX files? Why they interpret "\t" literally as "\t" and not as "TAB" when Mahtmeatica itself interprets it is "TAB"?

Comment: @azerbajdzan. I can't answer that. I'm just another Mathematica user. You could try asking Wolfram tech support.